# Overflows and spikes while doing gradient descent

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to find a function h(r) that minimises a functional H(h) by a very simple gradient descent algorithm. The result of H(h) is a single number. (Basically, I have a field configuration in space and I am trying to minimise the energy due to this field). The field is discretized in space, and the gradient used is the derivative of H with respect to the field's value at each discrete point in space. I am doing this on Mathematica, but I think the code is easy to follow for non-users of Mathematica.

The function Hamiltonian takes a vector of field values, the spacing of points d, and the number of points imax, and gives the value of energy. EderhSym is the function that gives a table of values for the derivatives at each point. I wrote the derivative function manually to save computation time. (The details of these two functions are probably irrelevant for the question).

```
Hamiltonian[hvect_, d_, imax_] := 
       Sum[(i^2/2)*d*(hvect[[i + 1]] - hvect[[i]])^2, {i, 1, imax - 1}] + 
       Sum[i^2*d^3*Potential[hvect[[i]]], {i, 1, imax}]

EderhSym[hvect_,d_,imax_]:=Join[{0},Table[2 i^2 d hvect[[i]]-i(i+1)d hvect[[i+1]]
-i(i-1)d hvect[[i-1]]+i^2 d^3 Vderh[hvect[[i]]], {i, 2, imax - 1}], {0}]
```

The code below shows a single iteration of gradient descent. hvect1 is some starting configuration that I have guessed using physical principles.

```
Ederh = EderhSym[hvect1, d, imax];

hvect1 = hvect1 - StepSize*Ederh;
```

The problem is that I am getting random spikes in the derivative table. The spikes keep growing until there is an overflow. I have tried changing the step size, I have tried using moving averages, low pass filters, Gaussian filters etc. I still get spikes that cause an overflow. Has anyone encountered this? Is it a problem with the way I am setting up gradient descent?

Aside - I am testing my gradient descent code as I will have to adapt it to a different multivariable Hamiltonian where I do this to find a saddle point instead: (n is an appropriately chosen small number, 10 in my case)

```
For[c = 1, c <= n, c++,
  Ederh = EderhSym[hvect1, \[CapitalDelta], imax];
  hvect = hvect - \[CapitalDelta]\[Tau]*Ederh;
  ];

Ederh = EderhSym[hvect1, \[CapitalDelta], imax];
hvect1 = hvect1 + n \[CapitalDelta]\[Tau]*Ederh;
```

Edit: It seems to be working with a much smaller step size than I had previously tried (although convergence is slow). I believe that was the problem, but I do not see why the divergences are localised at particular points.